# How to set a custom center point (pivot point) for the "copy location constraint" (include a simulation video in content)

Tags: constraints

I would like to know how to set a custom center/pivot point for the "copy location constraint”. So when we set the X/Y/Z invert of the copy location constraint, two objects can move toward the opposite directions within a certain area. Please see the simulation video:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bSmByVFAe1Na12U35pxzNZnx7k05Q2Zu

Currently, by default, the center point is on the world origin point (coordinates X,Y,Z=0,0,0), so when I set the copy location constraint with X/Y/Z invert, two objects are separate far far away according to the center point is on the world origin point. please see the recording video of the result of default setting:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cqONcr4gopfTiHIwQ96gmEb_yy9scNxC

Please download the testing blender file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lj128BZKfHOe8av16_At_7vneEjoKNVW

Thank you very much,

Ava

Thank you.

Please see the reference images and blender file below :

Comment: Two things come to mind. Can move the origin of the objects.  Can set a vertex group as the constraint target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use drivers as constraints: in your example the cursor is at 0,0,4. So X and Y can be managed by the copy location (inverted) constraint. Your ***new*** Z value has to be 4 - (Z**old** - 4). So you can set the Z driver as 8 - Z.

The same can be done with different X and Y values.

[image]

Another way can be set the copy location constraint in local space (instead of world space), check the offset option, then move both meshes to the pivot point (Shift S - selection to cursor).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works =) Thank you for reply so fast also, you're so kind 